# New Twitter API - they say no way to use ajax but will this work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, twitter

I am working on fixing an older connection string to Twitter's api that simply pulls the number of followers to display it.

The site is : www.democracywatch.ca
You can see the current request syntax when you "inspect element" on the empty Twitter square on the bottom right (it should have a number of followers and should display some of the most recent feeds).

The current code is jquery/ajax:

```
                    jQuery(function($) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json',
                        data: {screen_name: 'democracywatchr'},
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#followers div.twitter').html(data.followers_count);
                        }
                    });
```

You can see that I tried to replace http with https and I added .1 to before the /users in the url but now I am getting an "unauthorized" response from them. I understand that from now on I should do OAuth requests... but I am not sure what code to add to what I have now in order to authorize my request. My web app exists and I have the necessary tokens but am not sure about the method of implementing them into my current jQuery function.

I also found this: http://sobolev.us/how-to-use-twitter-oauth-v1-1-with-javascriptjquery/
Implementing that code is easy but how do I make a call for only my follower number to be the response?

Is there a way that you can think of implementing the tokens right into my current code?

Comment: This will not work. Due to security policies you are not allowed to do cross-domain AJAX calls. This is why the solution you refer to also uses PHP for the cross-domain calls. The easiest way would be to connect using a server side language like PHP. If you are only interested in the amount of followers I personally would write a simple function that parses the public Twitter page and parses it to retrieve the amount of followers. Although this is probably not the way Twitter approves.

Answer (score 0):

To continue my previous answer with a working example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("https://twitter.com/DemocracyWatchr");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$followers = $xpath->query("//a[@data-element-term='follower_stats']/strong")->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $followers;
```

Will give you the number of followers. Be warned: This will only work as long as Twitter doesn't change it's interface although a little rewriting should do the trick in this situation.

Comment: Vaishak: thank you very much for confirming! I knew that they don't allow cross-domain AJAX calls and this is also why they shut down API 1.0... I completely understand why as well...

Comment: Okmer: thank you! I will try to use your method and hopefully it works... thank you very much!

Comment: Hey !! I'm sorry for the long response... I kind of gave up on doing just DOM as I want it to be made the "correct" way. I am testing the calls on https://apigee.com/console and I am able to generate a response array that I want!! but I am a beginner with coding... I know a few things but this is really complex for me just because I don't know what to learn or which method to use to do it correctly. So you are saying that the correct way would be to make the call trough PHP and then use it? the AJAX call I have now also assigns the followers_count array item to a div ID..

Comment: Normally browsers don't allow you to do calls to external urls for safety reasons. Apigee.com is not the way it is going to work in a normal webpage. That's why I provided you with a example using PHP to do the external call.